# How to efficiently work with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's take a look at simple class examples:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public List<BookPage> Pages { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
} 

public class BookPage
{
    [Key]
    public string BookPageId { get; set; }
    public PageTitle PageTitle { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class PageTitle
{
    [Key]
    public string PageTitleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

So, if I want to get all PageTitiles, if I knew only the BookId, I need to write a few includes, like this:

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext
    .Book
    .Include(x => x.Pages)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.PageTitle)//.ThenInclude(x => x.Select(y => y.PageTitle)) Shouldn't use in EF Core
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
    .Pages
    .Select(x => x.PageTitle);
}
```

And if i want to get PageTitles connected with other book, I need to rewrite this method again, and nothing changed except the BookId! This is very inefficient way to work with database, in this example I have 3 classes, but if I had hundreds of classes, nested to the very deep level, it would be very slow and uncomfortable to work.

How exactly should I organize working with my database, to avoid many Includes, and redundant queries?

Comment: Pages in class book need to be declared as a virtual collection. PageTitle in bookPage should be declared a int PageTitleId and should have a Data Annotation of ForeignKey. PageTitleId in PageTitle should be declared as int and not string....just as a starter.

Comment: If your unsure about how EF works. Do DB first. Create the database in the database. Ensure you have Productivity power tools installed for VS and reverse engineer by pointing to the DB and EF will create all the classes etc for you.

Comment: @bilpor but, for example [here](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html) we have nly List, without any virtual keyword. And refers to [this](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#single-navigation-property), we don't need to define foreign keys. I'm sure how it's work, I'm not sure how to efficiently work with it.

Comment: Yes, you dont need to define FK's, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't. Come at it from the DB side. you might write the app your way with no FK's etc which might be fine because you can look at the code and look at the inheritance/ object graph to see the relationships. A while later a DBA comes along and wants to do some SSRS work and doesn't have access to you or the application code. Now they will have a hard time working out the relationships. Without FK's you start to loose the point of a relational DB such as SQL Server. It also means that records could be orphaned when you delete.

Comment: @bilpor but EF creates foreign keys instead of me.

Comment: Ok...but on our system we are explict `[ForeignKey("alertId")]`
        `public virtual Alert Alert { get; set; }`

Comment: @bilpor that's another question, where I don't want to have simple class with hundreds of foreign keys defined in it. Do we have another way?

Comment: under the hood EF builds SQL. with FK's in place when it comes to your linq statements, you would not necessarily write as per your example. you would use expression trees instead and these are pretty efficient, and you'd write a decent repository layer. There are plenty of example out there on how to do that, so I'm not going to do that here.

Comment: @bilpor could you please link to some example?

Comment: "if I had hundreds of classes, nested to the very deep level, it would be very slow and uncomfortable to work" Yes, yes it would.  Which is why no one builds data structures that are hundreds of levels deep.

Comment: What _exactly_ is your concern?  All of the includes?  Or having to write the query multiple times for each ID?  Either problem can be solved by encapsulating your logic in methods.

Comment: @DStanley both, but prefer to solve problem with a lot of includes. But demand to write dozens of queries, that's the problem too.

Comment: @YuriyN. Are you writing the _same_ query multiple times?  I don't see a way around writing multiple queries if the queries are all different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem 1:  I have to add a bunch of `Includes` each time.**

Well, there's not a way around that as you have to explicitly included related data in EF, but you can easily create an extension method to make it cleaner:

```
public static IQueryable<Book> GetBooksAndPages(this BookContext db)
{
    return db.Book.Include(x => x.Pages);
}

public static IQueryable<Book> GetBooksAndPagesAndTitles(this BookContext db)
{
    return GetBooksAndPages(db).ThenInclude(p => p.PageTitle)

}
```

Then you can just do:

```
var bookPages = dbContext
    .GetBooksAndPagesAndTitles()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
    .Pages
    .Select(x => x.PageTitle);
```

**Problem 2:  I have to write this query multiple times for different IDs.**

Why not just refactor that into a method with a `bookId` parameter?

```
public IEnumerable<PageTitle> GetPageTitlesForBook(BookContext dbContext, int bookId)
{
    return dbContext
        .GetBooksAndPagesAndTitles()
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == bookId)
        .Pages
        .Select(x => x.PageTitle);
}
```

Bottom line - if you find yourself writing the same thing many times, that's a perfect opportunity to refactor your code into smaller methods that can be re-used.

Comment: great idea with extension methods, could we use them with IQueryable instead of DbContext?

Comment: @YuriyN. Sure, you can create extension methods on virtually any type.

Comment: If you're using extension methods you clearly don't test your code. They're a pain.

Answer (score 2):

None of the examples given require any Include statements at all. If you are using a select at the end of your query and you are still operating on an IQueryable such as a DbSet, Entity Framework will perform what is known as a 'projection' and will run the query including all of the required fields for you automatically.

For example, your original code:

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext
        .Book
        .Include(x => x.Pages)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.PageTitle)//.ThenInclude(x => x.Select(y => y.PageTitle)) Shouldn't use in EF Core
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
        .Pages
        .Select(x => x.PageTitle);
}
```

You can rewrite this like so:

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext
        .Book
        .Where(x => x.BookId == "some example id")
        .SelectMany(x => x.Pages.Select(y => y.PageTitle))
        .ToList();
}
```

Here's what Entity Framework will do to resolve this:

1. We tell Entity Framework that we're going to look at entries from the books table
2. We then tell Entity Framework that we only want the books with a specific ID (which should just be a single record, of course)
3. From there, for each book we tell Entity Framework that we want a list of all of that books pages (again, this will just be one book's pages because of the Where statement)
4. Then we tell Entity Framework that we want just the PageTitle from each Page
5. **Finally, we tell Entity Framework to use all of the information we've just provided to generate a query and execute it**

The last step is the crucial one if you want to understand how Entity Framework does what it does. In your example when you call `SingleOrDefault` you are instructing Entity Framework to execute the query, which is why you need the includes. In your example you haven't actually told Entity Framework that you need the pages when you run the query, so you have to manually request them using `Include`.

In the example I've posted, you can see that by the time you run the query (`ToList` is what triggers the query execution) Entity Framework knows from your Select expression that it is going to need the pages, and their titles. Even better - this means Entity Framework will not even include unused columns in the `SELECT` statement that it generates.

I highly recommend investigating projections, they're probably the best way I know of to remove the requirement to continuously manually include stuff.

Comment: Very interesting, was it in the EF Core 1.0?

Comment: Yes this behaviour has always existed. It's one of my favourite features of EF 

Comment: Where have you been two years ago... Thanks, I'll try that feature also!

Comment: @YuriyN. since reading up on this further, it appears that nested projections have been somewhat unreliable (or just plain missing in EF Core 1.0). I believe this is more or less resolved now and the above will work, but I'd need to check. It certainly works in EF for .NET Framework but I didn't realise they neglected to include nested progressions in EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

I somehow missed this was EF Core (despite the title). Try this instead:

```
public class BookPage
{
    [Key]
    public string BookPageId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public PageTitle PageTitle { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }   // Add FK if desired
}
```

Now to get all page titles for a book:

```
// pass the book you want in as a parameter, viewbag, etc.
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var bookPages = dbContext.BookPages
        .Include(p => p.Book)
        .Include(p => p.PageTitle)
        .Where(p => p.Book.BookId == myBookId)
        .Select(p => new { 
            Bookid = p.Book.BookId,
            Text = p.Book.Text,
            PageNumber = p.Number,
            PageTitle = p.PageTitle.Title
        });
}
```

Comment: we don't have lazy loading in Entity Framework Core, that's the problem, only Include we can use. So, your example doesn't work.

Comment: OK, try it with Includes() then. That's why I'm sticking with EF6 for now :)

Comment: yes, it works, but has no difference with the question's example :)

Comment: What are you looking for? I tried to give you a more robust example. LINQ to entities is pretty powerful if you use it right.

Comment: I'm looking for the right way to work with deep nested data, which lays at the end of the tables chain. For example, the Book the basic class, while the PageTitle is deep nested.

Comment: I wouldn't call that deep nested, but it's all relative. If you are talking 5 or 6 levels deep, then you may want to look at stored procedures, views or multiple fetches. Include() is the tool of choice for nested data. The docs show common scenarios: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Book and PageTitle were just for example. Ok, theres is no option except Include, which is perefect for this scenario.

Comment: The `Include` statements can be removed from this example, it will work fine without them.

Answer (score 1):

I would have built the model like this:

```
    public class Book
    {
        // a property "Id" or ClassName + "Id" is treated as primary key. 
        // No annotation needed.
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        // without [StringLenth(123)] it's created as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        // optionally if you need the pages in the book object:
        // Usually I saw ICollections for this usage.
        // Without lazy loading virtual is probably not necessary.
        public virtual ICollection<BookPage> BookPages { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookPage
    {
        public int BookPageId { get; set; }

        // With the following naming convention EF treats those two property as 
        // on single database column. This automatically corresponds
        // to ICollection<BookPage> BookPages of Books.
        // Required is not neccessary if "BookId" is int. If not required use int?
        // A foreign key relationship is created automatically. 
        // With RC2 also an index is created for all foreign key columns.
        [Required]
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public PageTitle PageTitle { get; set; }
        public int PageTitleId { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class PageTitle
    {
        public int PageTitleId { get; set; }

        // without StringLenth it's created as NVARCHAR(MAX)
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

As you had a collection of `BookPage` in `Book` a foreign key is created in `BookPage`. In my model I have exposed this explicitly in `BookPage`. And not only with the object `Book` but also with the key `BookId`. The created tables are quite the same but now you can access the `BookId` without using the `Book` table.

```
    using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
    {
        var pageTitles = dbContext.BookPages
            .Include(p => p.PageTitle)
            .Where(p => p.BookId == myBookId)
            .Select(p => p.PageTitle);
    }
```

I would recommend to activate logging or to use the profiler to check which SQL statements are actually executed.

Regarding to the comments of @bilpor:
I found out that I did not need many DataAnnotations and almost no fluent API mappings. Primary and foreign keys are created automatically if you use the designated naming conventions. For foreign key relationships I only needed `[InverseProperty()]` on the collections if I had two foreign key relationships on the same two classes. Currently I only used fluent API mappings for composite primary keys (m:n tables) and to define the discriminator in a TPH structure.

Hint:
Currently there are bugs in EF Core which lead to client side evaluation of constraints.

```
.Where(p => p.BookId == myBookId)  // OK 
.Where(p => p.BookId == myObject.BookId) // client side 
.Where(p => p.BookId == myBookIdList[0]) // client side
```

Same is true when you use Contains() and you mix nullable and not nullable data types.

```
.Where(p => notNullableBookIdList.Contains(p.NullableBookId)) // client side
```